# Telephone Key Pad Combination

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion

For homework I am trying to print all possible combinations of letters that can be represented using the numeric keypad on a telephone. This problem is the same as the one posted here: [How can I print out all possible letter combinations a given phone number can represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344496/how-can-i-print-out-all-possible-letter-combinations-a-given-phone-number-can-re)

I keep getting a String index out of range: 0 problem but I'm not 100% sure why. Here is the code:

```
public class TelephoneKeyPad2 {
public static String keyPad[][] = {
        {"0"}, {"1"}, {"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"}, {"G", "H", "I"},
        {"J", "K", "L"}, {"M", "N", "O"}, {"P", "Q", "R", "S"},
        {"T", "U", "V"}, {"W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
};

public static void tpK(String num, StringBuilder combination) {
    if (num.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    }

    for (String letter: keyPad[Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(0))]) {
        tpK(num.substring(1), combination.append(letter));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    tpK("345", new StringBuilder());
} }
```

I have a feeling it's because of the if statement...there is no way to break the recursion after num.length == 0 is confirmed to be true, so the string index out of range. I am not sure how to fix this problem and any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: So it seems like it may be just a logic problem then afterwards.

DGJ

DGJK

DGJKL

DGJKLHJ

DGJKLHJK

are example outputs so now I'm really confused on how to solve this problem as well.

Comment: "There is no way to break the recursion"--use a `return` statement or an else statement in order to allow the second half of the `tpK` method run *only* when `num.length()` isn't zero.

Comment: Thanks for the responses...however it also seems like my logic is off as well.

After adding the else statement in (or return statement), it returns: 
    DGJ
DGJK
DGJKL
DGJKLHJ
DGJKLHJK
DGJKLHJKL
DGJKLHJKLIJ
DGJKLHJKLIJK
DGJKLHJKLIJKL
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJ
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJK
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJKL
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJKLHJ
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJKLHJK
DGJKLHJKLIJKLEGJKLHJKL

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` statement so that the for loop only gets executed when there is more than 0 characters:

```
public static void tpK(String num, StringBuilder combination) {
    if (num.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    } else {

        for (String letter: keyPad[Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(0))]) {
            tpK(num.substring(1), combination.append(letter));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the other problem I had. Turns it out the StringBuilder seems to create a static object(?). When the program goes through recursion, it only instantiates one object. I changed the StringBuilder type to String and used the concat method instead, solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If `num.length()` is 0, you still go on to ask for `num.charAt(0)`.

Comment: While this is a true statement, it seems that the OP is asking about how to break the recursion in order to prevent exactly what you're pointing out.

Comment: `I keep getting a String index out of range: 0 problem but I'm not 100% sure why` - this is why. Perhaps OP should be asking 2 different question ;-)